# How to setup Dotnetnuke Scheduled Job on ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, dotnetnuke

How can I setup a custom Scheduler Task in DotNetNuke to run my own automated code?

Answer (score 4):

In `DNN` it's easy, just add a `class` to `App_Code` folder (*or to any `class library`*), then add following codes in that `class`:

```
using System;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling;

namespace A
{
    public class B : SchedulerClient
    {
        public B(ScheduleHistoryItem scheduleHistoryItem)
        {
            base.ScheduleHistoryItem = scheduleHistoryItem;
        }

        public override void DoWork()
        {
            try
            {
                this.MyMethod();
                base.ScheduleHistoryItem.Succeeded = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                base.ScheduleHistoryItem.Succeeded = false;
                base.ScheduleHistoryItem.AddLogNote("Oops!! something went wrong!");
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapP‌​ath("/SchedulerLog.t‌​xt"), ex.ToString());
                base.Errored(ref ex);
            }
        }

        public void MyMethod()
        {
            // your logic here ...
            // this codes will be run by DNN
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapP‌​ath("/SchedulerLog.t‌​xt"), "Scheduler fired! at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Head over to `tabid/25` and click `Add Item to Schedule` button, in opened window, give your schedule a name, in second `textbox` (*Full Class Name and Assembly*) you need to enter full class name (*namespace.className*), based on my mentioned code, it will be `A.B`, change other options as you wish, click `Update`, and you are ready to go :)

p.s: In `tabid/25` page, in schedule's list, by clicking on `Log`, you can see if the schedule run successfully or not. hope this help.

**Update because of Chris's comment**

The `TabId` of `Schedule` page is `25` by default (*in DNN v7.x at least*), but if it's not for you, so looking for `Host > Schedule` in menu.

Comment: Not everyone's schedule page will be TabId/25 FYI

Comment: My Database isn't update! [Here is my steps > click here to show images](http://imgur.com/a/HjtNN) Can't you help me!

Comment: Also as you can see, under `Succeeded` column (picture #3), there is no checked checkbox, that means something is wrong in your code. you need to check `ErrorLog` for find put what is wrong in your code.

Comment: @NamNguyễn I updated my answer, is your code is the same as mine (updated one)?

Comment: not working! Succesed checkbox is false :( Can you TeamView for me?

Comment: @NamNguyễn Update your code as mine, & looking for `/SchedulerLog.txt` and put the content somewhere & drop the link here

Comment: Not found SchedulerLog.txt on my location project :(

Comment: Can you share site & superuser login info?

Comment: [IMAGE](http://imgur.com/a/q7MtQ) what's .dll file? Your code posted, i copied and paste on the .cs file! My website is install on the localhost

Comment: @NamNguyễn I added lot of scheduler using my mentioned code, I'm sure it works, please take a look at https://codepaste.net/vujsyd, also read my description

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no any other idea, I tired the code & it works for me, without accessing to your website, I can't do anything more.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help and for your support!

Answer (score 2):

In short you build a DLL that the DNN scheduler can run in the background at given intervals. You then use the DNN scheduled task interface to set up this DLL once you have added it to the DNN /bin folder.

I've built a sample project which demonstrates a DNN scheduled task in C# with a separate project that can run the task code outside of DNN to make debugging easier.

You can read my blog post about it here:

http://www.bilgewater.co.uk/post/20/1/2017/Build-and-Debug-a-DNN-Scheduled-Task

The source code is available on Github here:

https://github.com/GusBeare/DNNSchedule

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

DNN has a build-in Scheduler which can run various tasks that have already been added. It can be found under `Host > Schedule`. It has predefined tasks like `Purge Cache` and `Send Log Notifications`, some of which are disabled.

If you want your own task you will have to create your own. The following sites have info about that.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/135088/creating-dotnetnuke-scheduled-jobs

http://dnnuke.blogspot.nl/2010/07/not-tutorial-creating-my-first-dnn.html

http://www.revindex.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryID/36

http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/Develop-and-deploy-DNN-Schedule-Task

Comment: What is type file to create Scheduler ?

Comment: A library (.dll) file.